# Setting different app icons depends upon the configurations in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

I want to set different app icons depends upon the configurations like Debug, Release in iOS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer from below question.

Look this: [How can I configure my iPhone project to use a seperate application icon for beta releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317481/how-can-i-configure-my-iphone-project-to-use-a-seperate-application-icon-for-bet)

Thanks